Throttling Exceptions for AWS Config
I am a developer and when I am making a request for the action - DescribeConfigurationAggregators, I seem to be hitting throttling exceptions for the very first request. This behaviour seems to be common to many of my AWS accounts and I have seen this behaviour with listing tags for aws-config-rules as well.
Has anyone else encountered this issue ever? I can't find anything in public documentations or anywhere else the same behaviour for any service.
I tried tuning the maxResults value but to no avail.
